# How to create a 24h window of 30-minute intervals of a year's worth of datetime data and average the number of occurences in each 30-minute interval

Tags: r

For example, when patients arrive at the hospital, the date and time of arrival are registered (15/04/2018 6:60:30). over a year, tens of thousands of patients are registered and I am interested in getting an aggregate distribution of patient arrival within a 24-hour window.

one of the columns of my data frame contains date/time values (like the table below), spanning two different years. Each observation represents the arrival of a patient.

```
31/12/2017 20:24
31/12/2017 21:24
31/12/2017 21:34
31/12/2017 22:55
31/12/2017 22:55
31/12/2017 23:18
31/12/2017 23:37
31/12/2017 23:37
31/12/2017 23:49
01/01/2018 0:15
01/01/2018 0:23
01/01/2018 0:56
01/01/2018 1:08
01/01/2018 1:27
01/01/2018 2:44
```

I want to figure out the average arrival per 30-minute interval given a 24-hour window and a 7-day window.

I just don't know how to get it done. Newbie here! Please, I need your assistance. Thanks

I tried this

```
arrivaltime <- dmy_hm(mydata$Time.of.arrival, tz = "US/Eastern")
head(arrivaltime)

MyArrivalDatesTable<-data.frame(table((cut(arrivaltime,breaks = "30 mins"))))
head(MyArrivalDatesTable)
```

But I still don't get the correct output.

the expected results:

7-day window

```
Day Time    mean arrival 
Mon 0:00    1.057534247
Mon 0:30    1.087671233
Mon 1:00    0.882191781
Mon 1:30    0.745205479
Mon 2:00    0.64109589
Mon 2:30    0.589041096
Mon 3:00    0.652054795
Mon 3:30    0.663013699
Mon 4:00    0.616438356
...
24-h window

Time    mean arrival
0:00    1.057534247
0:30    1.087671233
1:00    0.882191781
1:30    0.745205479
2:00    0.64109589
2:30    0.589041096
3:00    0.652054795
3:30    0.663013699
4:00    0.616438356
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

count(weekday = wday(arrivaltime), 
      hour    = floor_date(arrivaltime, "30 minutes")) %>%
mutate(mean_arrival = n / 365)
```